# Ruby how to generate a random number from a given number

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I know how to generate a random number within a range in ruby:

```
rand(10..45)
```

but how to generate a number form a given number?

example:

```
def generate_random_number(n)
  #what to put here
end
```

if I run:

```
generate_random_number(123)
```

it will return an array of possible generated number from given number:

```
[123, 321, 231, 132 etc ...]
```

is there any ruby function to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
123.to_s.chars.permutation.map {|a| a.join.to_i}
# => [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

If you want the order to be random, [`shuffle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) it:

```
123.to_s.chars.permutation.map {|a| a.join.to_i}.shuffle
# => [312, 123, 213, 132, 231, 321]
```